# Will apple human interface guidelines violated if i put tab bar on top?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, tabbar

I am developing an app in which i am putting tab bar on top as per requirements.I know apple put tab bar at bottom with maximum 5 tabs.So if make my own custom tab bar & i put it on top.

I have two questions.

1. **Will apple human interface guidelines will be violated?**
2. **If i violate apple human interface guidelines will apple reject the 
   app on app store?**

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
1. Yes, that's not the appearance on tab bars on iOS
2. No

Long answer:
As long as you're designing the tab bar (that's what you call it) to be easy to use and it's clear to understand its purpose, then no harm is made. If, however, there is no clear purpose, why move it?

Apple will not reject apps that violates the HIG, but the HIG is created to be followed, to create a consistent experience for all users, regarding app.

Comment: can you please provide me the link where i can find it is written that apple will not reject the app if HIG is not followed.I need to show it to someone.@Simon

Comment: no, there's no written proof. if you can't argue that this design solution is the best, it's probably isn't.

Comment: Well I think it depends upon what guideline you are violating.